# The import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection cannot be resolved

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to import the class javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection but it cannot be resolved or found into the related package. I declare the import as is, but it returns this message:

```
The import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection cannot be resolved
```

Comment: It should be part of the JDK, what JDK version are you using?

Comment: The JDK currently used is the 11 (JRE 17.0.4.1)

Comment: *(JRE 17.0.4.1)* is *not* a JDK. Can you compile *any* code? Do you actually *have* a compiler?

Comment: I'm doing that via Eclipse with that given jre

Comment: Other code compiles?

Comment: It does with any particular issue.